# Regular expression for time period

Tags: regex, oracle-adf

I am using jdev 12.2.1.0.0 and I am trying to validated an input field(String) with the ""
in which i am try to enter period of time in  formats shown below

- 1h 40m 20s
- 1h 40m
- 2h 30s
- 30m 20s
- 30m
- 30 (It will be considered as 30m)
- 10s

So I need a regular expression which allow a user to enter the period of time in any given format also no need to consider the space between the unit (ie: 1h30m is also valid).

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Sorry, but this is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that matches all the cases you wanted:

```
((\d{1,2}h\s?)?(\d{1,2}m\s?)?(\d{1,2}s\s?)?)|\d{1,2}
```

#### [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KIl9UF/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :
`^(?:\d+h)?(?:(?!\n)\s)?(?:\d+m?)?(?:(?!\n)\s)?(?:\d+s)?$`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Zn54Al/2)

Answer (score 0):

Matches all the cases.
And the minutes/seconds have to be between 0 and 59 if there's more than 1 period:

```
^(?:\d+[hms]?|\d+h(?:[ ]*[0-5]?\dm)?(?:[ ]*[0-5]?\ds)?|\d+m[ ]*[0-5]?\ds)$
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/dpyonK/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]+[d|h|m|s|D|H|M|S]?[^$]?([0-9]+[h|m|s|H|M|S]?[^$]?)?([0-9]+[m|s|M|S]?[^$]?)?([0-9]+[s|S]?[^$])?
```

None of the other answers worked for my purpose.
But thanks to this I studied little more about Regex.
so just remember [0-9] indicates a single digit and + is to extend it to multiple digits. [d|h|m|s|] indicates any letters in d,h,m or s. you can probably add days or hours whatever you like. ? is to make the precedings as optional.

https://regex101.com/r/dpyonK/17